# Is there a way to make ant design pagination rows per page always show up?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am currently using ant design in my reactJs application and I notice that `Pagination` `rowsPerPage` drop-down only appear when `totalElement` is greater than the maximum option in `rowsPerPage`. Is there a way I can make `rowsPerPage` always visible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it only show dropdown (Actually it is called sizeChanger Dropdown) when total > 50.

If you want to show sizeChanger dropdown manually, you can pass `showSizeChanger: true` as prop in pagination component.

```
<Pagination showQuickJumper total={...} />
```

Please check Antd Pagination API for all the options you can pass to pagination component. [Antd Pagination API](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#API)

**TLDR**

If you want to override the dropdown `pageSize`, you can pass your custom values in `pageSizeOptions`:

```
<Pagination showQuickJumper total={...}. pageSizeOptions: [15, 20, 30, 40, 50] />
```